# how to call font-face using domain url not local path

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'Poppins-Light';
    src:url(http://mdinfosystems.co.in/demo/mdnew/fonts/Poppins-Light.ttf) 
    format('truetype');
}
```

trying to call this font using domain url but its not working and location is absolutely perfect, even when you paste this url to your browser it will automatically give you the font file. and yet I don't understand why its not working for my website. I have searched on searched on google about this I found a few codes to add on my website but I don't understand where I have to add these codes in the css of server or html file where, below I have mentioned the code I found on google search:

```
"AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>"
```

Comment: If you check the console, the TTF file request is being blocked by the Same Origin Policy: http://jsfiddle.net/hfx4fpa7/. I'd suggest you download the font and host it on your own server - assuming you have the legal right to use it.

Comment: The code you found on google search has to be implemented by the server that is hosting and serving the font: it's not something the consumer (i.e. you) can use. The server is preventing cross origin requests on the font file (as what Rory said above) so that people cannot hotlink the file on their sites, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert this font to a web font first, using this service:

https://transfonter.org/

I have done it with your font:

https://transfonter.org/files/eafb2ae175df7972c13c5ea3565a2129/demo.html?1504251859

Then you will need to host the font files somewhere and the end product generated css should look like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Poppins';
src: url('Poppins-Light.eot');
src: url('Poppins-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('Poppins-Light.woff') format('woff'),
    url('Poppins-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: 300;
font-style: normal;
```

}

They will provide you will all the code and font files that you need.